# Shape of weights in hidden layer(Multilayer Perceptron)

Tags: numpy, machine-learning

Trying to build a Multilayer perceptron using only NumPy with iris flower dataset but I'm stuck with this:

1. Input layer of 4 nodes(iris dataset is shaped `(112,4)`).
2. I want that my hidden layer consists of 3 nodes, so in theory, the correct shape would be `(112,3)`?

I know that each input has its own weights example:
`input[0]` has `weight[0]` etc..
The question is what shape should my random init weights have to be able to perform the dot product correct in order to get the right hidden layer output?

Comment: What does your data input shaped `(112,4)` represent?

Comment: 4 columns which are the features of the dataset and the 112 rows total record number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of parameters of your function should not depend on the number of entries in your dataset. From your comment it, you are having `112` feature of size `4` and you want to project those with a linear functia on to feature size of `3`. A fully connected layer comes down to matrix multiplication with optionally an additive bias. So in your case you only need to use a `4x3` matrix.

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(112,4)
>>> m = np.random.rand(4,3)
```

Inference:

```
>>> out = x@m # __maltmul__
>>> out.shape
(112, 3)
```

You could also add a bias:

```
>>> b = np.random.rand(1,3)
>>> out = x@m + b
```

Comment: yes only that this is the total size of the dataset [112,4] so it would mean 4 features example:

[0.42855751, 0.81981226, 0.37319627, 0.05064203]
sepal.length sepal.width petal.length petal.width

112 would mean 112 records(total size of the dataset)

Comment: thats a correct answer but then all the data would share the same weights of a hidden layer ?
n=np.random.randn(112,4)
m = np.random.rand(4,3)
would this be the right behavior ?

Comment: Yes, the point **is** to share weights across your entire dataset. If each instance of your dataset had a dedicated set of weights then your model would be perfectly overfitting your data, do you see my point?

Comment: yes totally we would then train a model for each record which doesn't make sense,thanks a lot Ivan